# Modificar orientación de escritura

Tags: html, css

tengo una duda en lo que a la orientación de escritura en html se refiere:

Necesito que, en vez de escribirse de izquierda a derecha, se escriba de derecha a izquierda.

**NOTA:** No me refiero al uso de `dir="rtl"`, ya que con ello si quiero escribir "hola", se escribiría "aloh".

Gracias adelantadas

**EDIT**: No puedo hacer uso de `float`

Comment: Entonces te referís a escribir el texto en orientación a la derecha, por ej: `hola como estas?` se lea `estas? como hola`? O que el texto esté alineado en la derecha?

Comment: Que el texto se alinee a la derecha @Kleith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El atributo dir especifica la dirección del texto del contenido del elemento.
Es decir, no lo invierte, como mencionas.

LTR : Left to right

```html
<p dir="ltr">Write this text left-to-right!</p>
```

RTL: right-to-left

```html
<p dir="rtl">Write this text right-to-left!</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

si entendi bien lo que quieres es que el texto empiese de derecha a izquierda o de izquierda a derecha? si es asi usa esto en css

```
{
  text-align:left;

}

{
   text-align:right;
}
```